# How to move an undecorated JFrame window?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, window

So I've been working on a program and I wanted to make it borderless with `jframe.setUndecorated(true);`. However, I can't really move the JFrame window around the screen. Is there a way I can fix that?

Here is my current code for the JFrame:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(700, 450);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move the JFrame, left-click inside the JFrame somewhere, drag the mouse to the new position, and release the mouse button when the JFrame is in the correct position.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MoveUndecoratedJFrame implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MoveUndecoratedJFrame());
    }
    
    private JFrame frame;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        MoveListener listener = new MoveListener();
        panel.addMouseListener(listener);
        panel.addMouseMotionListener(listener);
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 400));
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public class MoveListener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
        
        private Point pressedPoint;
        private Rectangle frameBounds;
        private Date lastTimeStamp;

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            this.frameBounds = frame.getBounds();
            this.pressedPoint = event.getPoint();
            this.lastTimeStamp = new Date();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
            moveJFrame(event);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
            moveJFrame(event);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
        }
        
        private void moveJFrame(MouseEvent event) {
            Point endPoint = event.getPoint();

            int xDiff = endPoint.x - pressedPoint.x;
            int yDiff = endPoint.y - pressedPoint.y;

            Date timestamp = new Date();

            //One move action per 60ms to avoid frame glitching
            if(Math.abs(timestamp.getTime() - lastTimeStamp.getTime()) > 60){ 
                if((xDiff>0 || yDiff>0)||(xDiff<0 || yDiff<0)) {
                    frameBounds.x += xDiff;
                    frameBounds.y += yDiff;
                    System.out.println(frameBounds);
                    owner.setBounds(frameBounds);
                }
                this.lastTimeStamp = timestamp;
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```